# vim and sudo vim using different settings on openSUSE

Tags: linux, vim, sudo, folding

I want vim to save folded code after I've closed the file. I've added the following code to both /etc/vimrc and ~/.vimrc:

```
au BufWinLeave ?* mkview
au BufWinEnter ?* silent loadview
```

When I open a file as a regular user (vim file) it works as expected. If I instead open with sudo vim file it doesn't save folded code.

I know /etc/vimrc is being read. My theme is set at the bottom of that file and is working fine. I ran into a similar problem last week installing the vim surround plugin. When that was installed in ~/.vim it only applied to vim file. To get it working with sudo I had to install it separately in /usr/share/vim/current. What could be causing this?

Comment: `sudo -E vim` should attempt to start Vim with your environment variables preserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Prolog

In fact you answered your question, so this is indeed the same issue you had before. It is caused by the algorithm Vim uses to find its configuration (see `:help initialization`). But I wouldn't call your solution a correct one. See `:help $VIM` for information how you can use your configuration in `sudo` environment (e.g. being `root`).

### As for your current issue.

See the following quotes from the documentation. `:help :mkview`:

```
:mkvie[w][!] [file] ...
        When [file] is omitted or is a number from 1 to 9, a
        name is generated and 'viewdir' prepended.
                    ...
```

And `:help 'viewdir'`:

```
 'viewdir' 'vdir'   string (default for ... for Unix: "~/.vim/view", ...
```

So after doing `sudo` all views are stored by Vim at `/root/.vim`.

### Solution

Make `viewdir` point to your `~/.vim/view` directory, with something like the following in `/root/.vimrc`:

```
:set viewdir=/home/user/.vim/view
```

Though, this approach has some issues itself:

1. Updating views saved by root will cause permission errors.
2. You wont be able to pass stored views for files under `/root` or `/home/user`, because Vim generates file names with tilde instead of full paths.

The first issue can be solved by running `chown` or `chmod` on new view file right after executing `:mkview` command. It should be something like:

```
execute '!chown user:group' eval('&viewdir').'/'.substitute(expand('%:p:~'), '/', '+=', 'g').'='
```

But I don't know good solution for the second issue, can only suggest writing a script to convert file names to full paths.

Comment: Thanks. Setting the viewdir is enough of a solution for me. I'm not seeing permission errors. 
I was worried this might not play nice with git, but since everything is saved in .vim/view that isn't an issue.